# SwiftUI: Run code whenever FetchedResults changes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm new to Core Data and struggling to find a simple solution to the below scenario.

I have a view like this:

```
struct SomeView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)

private var items: FetchedResults<Item>


var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            // Render item view
        }
    }
}
```

}

And I want to run an arbitrary handler whenever `Items` has changed. The list view updates as I expect, but I'm not sure how I should trigger non-ui code (say to send an API request every time Items changes). What is the simplest way to do this?

Searching around I'm seeing answers to similar questions point to `NSFetchedResultsController` and articles like [this](https://cargath.github.io/blog/2019/06/25/SwiftUI-NSFetchedResultsController), but I haven't seen a clear example of how to implement exactly what I want. If the answer truly is `NSFetchedResultsController`, could someone show me complete code to get this working?

EDIT: I seem to be able to achieve what I want by adding something like `let _ = handleItemsChanged(items: items)` inside the list view, but this seems hacky. Any cleaner mechanisms that are equally simple?

Comment: Could you help clarify what exactly you want to update when values change? Do you want the list to re-load when "items" is updated?

Comment: Let's say I want to send an API request every time the list changes (create, update, delete). The list UI updates appropriately and is not the issue here. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Seems like the `View` rendering is probably not the right place to handle that. Presumably, you have some code that *causes* the list to change. That's where you would introduce your side-effect that would send an API request.

Comment: @Toop gotcha! Have you tried the .onChange function? On the closing bracket of your List { .... }.onChange(of: items) { .... ----- here is the link to the apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/onchange(of:perform:)

Comment: @jnpx that is certainly an option but doesn't feel scalable. As my app is currently, I create, update and delete items from within three different components, via three different functions. I could copy and paste my desired side-effect in each of these locations but that gets messy quickly.

My list view doesn't need to be updated from each location, it just receives updates via Core Data no matter where the change originates from. Seems like I should be able to tap into that existing functionality somehow?

Comment: @nickreps Yes I can't seem to observe a FetchedResults type `instance method 'onChange(of:perform:)' requires that 'Binding<FetchedResults<Item>>' conform to 'Equatable'`

I also cannot mark the `FetchedResults` as `@ObservedObject`, this type does not implement that protocol either.

Comment: @Toop -- jnpx has a good suggestion. When the trigger occurs that leads to your database data to change, that same trigger would be a good place to make your api call. For example - a user adds some data to their list and clicks "Save" - save will both save the data to core data, and trigger the api call. Could something like that work? I should also add: .onChange works well with other property wrappers (@State, @ObservedObject) so if you can make your code work with those, you could potentially use .onChange on that list

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For network calls tied to view lifetime and data we use [`task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) and the async code within is cancelled and restarted when the `id` param changes, it is also cancelled when view disappears. To run the task when the number of items changes, you could do:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            // Render item view
        }
    }
    .task(id: items.count) {
        print("perform async network task")
        // e.g. stateHoldingResult = await something
    }
}
```

For updated items, you could create a computed var using data from the items you'd like to compare (i.e. check for changes) and supply that as the `id` param.